# Correcting DC offset in op-amp based controlled current source

Tags: measurement, current-source, voltage-measurement

In an attempt to develop an automated potentiometer measuring device I have implemented the following op-amp based voltage controlled current source, controlled by the output of a DAC. The voltage across two terminals of the potentiometer is then measured using a differential ADC (not pictured) from which one of the resistances is found.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLtLBm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I'm having a problem with this circuit in that the DC offset introduced in the op-amp is causing problems when the potentiometer resistance is low. The measured voltage goes negative instead of positive, or remaining at 0V.

To correct this I am thinking of using a chopper-stabilized op amp to minimise the DC offset. This would also need to be rail-to-rail as the supply it is driven from is a single supply +15V. Do these exist?

My question is: would this suitably reduce the DC offset? Or is there a compensation technique I could use in this circuit to reduce the offset?

Comment: *The measured voltage goes negative instead of positive, or remaining at 0V.* Is this the voltage of the DAC?

Comment: Where is the potentiometer? Where are you measuring? Show us the whole circuit.

Comment: The potentiometer is represented by the 10k resistor above the FET. And yes the DAC voltage goes low, with it usually sitting at maybe 20mV when V1 is 0

Comment: DAC = 20mV when V1 = 0V ... I thought V1 was the DAC output? (*op-amp ... controlled by the output of a DAC*). I'd recommend to update the question/schematic indication R2 is the potentiometer (also refered to as "10k load" ??). V1 being the DAC? And the DAC being controlled by the ADC?

Comment: @Huisman apologies for not making the question clear enough. I'm going to try a chopper-stabilized op-amp and try and see if I can generally improve the circuit myself since this question has gone poorly. Next time I ask about it I'll have a better schematic and some measurements to clarify.

Comment: I was considering suggesting to deliberately add another offset and calibrate/compensate for for both. (So, the *measured voltage goes* not *negative*). But without knowing the setup, I don't know if this even makes sense.